# React Native Android build Error : Failed to apply plugin 'com.android.internal.library'

Tags: android, react-native, android-studio

Faced error:

```bash
Failed to apply plugin 'com.android.internal.library'. > Android Gradle plugin requires Java 11 to run. You are currently using Java 1.8
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```bash
brew tap homebrew/cask-versions
brew install --cask zulu11
```